# I'm cloning a repo with Yeoman, what configuration do I need on my computer?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I have cloned a repo that has Yeoman installed.

I installed node, as well as Yeoman `npm i -g yo`. When I run `grunt` I get an error stating:

`Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.`

What else do I need to do to be able to run this repo successfully?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first time, you have to run npm install.

This will install all the needed dependencies as described in the `package.json`

Subsequently, if anyone add a new dependency into this file, you will need to run `npm install` or `npm update` again.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks so much Aurélien!

Answer (score 6):

Actually besides npm, you should also download bower dependencies.
So it's 2-step:

- `npm install`
- `bower install`

If you don't invoke bower application may launch, but later you may encounter problems such as the lack of libraries.